# Object Storage in python

Tags: python

What is the reason of following behavior of python:

```
p=89
x=89
print(p.__repr__,x.__repr__)
```

ans=`<method-wrapper '__repr__' of int object at 0x00000000623E78E0> <method-wrapper '__repr__' of int object at 0x00000000623E78E0>`

Here **repr** returns same location. I have read online that python tags values (unlike C and Java it does not assign value to variable but assign variable to value.)

But it gives different location for following code:

```
p=898
x=898
print(p.__repr__,x.__repr__)
```

here it gives result as

```
<method-wrapper '__repr__' of int object at 0x0000000005E8D370> <method-wrapper '__repr__' of int object at 0x0000000005E8D530>
```

What is the reason for this strange behaviour?

Comment: Firstly, `__repr__` is a method which you should actually call: `p.__repr__()`. Secondly, you shouldn't actually call that, you should call the built-in function: `repr(p)`. Thirdly, if you want the ID, you should call the `id()` function, not `repr()`. Fourthly, no, Python doesn't "tag" values.

Comment: mehtod repr() returns value of p in python3.6. so x.__repr__ is what I wants to use. id also represents same behaviour.

Comment: No it doesn't, and no it isn't. All you're doing is printing the string representation of a method - hence `method-wrapper` - which happens to include (in its own `__repr__`, but that's irrelevant) the ID of the object it is called on. And the linked question explains exactly why the IDs work that way.

Comment: Yes linked question answers my query. Thank you